# How to get text that has no tag with htmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have an html file like below

```
  <div>

  <div style="margin-left:0.5em;">
  <div class="tiny" style="margin-bottom:0.5em;">
  <b><span class="h3color tiny">This review is from: </span>You Meet</b>
  </div>
  If you know Ron Kaufman as I do ...
  <br /><br />Whether you're the CEO....
  <br /><br />Written in a distinctive, ...
  <br /><br />My advice? Don't just get one copy
  <div style="padding-top: 10px; clear: both; width: 100%;"></div>
  </div>

  <div style="margin-left:0.5em;">
  <div class="tiny" style="margin-bottom:0.5em;">
  <b><span class="h3color tiny">This review is from: </span>My Review</b>
  </div>
  I became a fan of Ron Kaufman after reading an earlier book of his years ago...
  <div style="padding-top: 10px; clear: both; width: 100%;"></div>
  </div>

  </div>
```

I want to get review text which doesnt have any html tag.
I am using below code now

```
  foreach (HtmlNode divReview in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//div[@style='margin-left:0.5em;']"))   
   {
      if (divReview != null)
          {

 review.Add(divReview.Descendants("div").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("style") && 
 d.Attributes["style"].Value.Contains("padding-top: 10px; clear: both; width: 100%;")).
                                          Select(d =>
 d.PreviousSibling.InnerText.Trim()).SingleOrDefault());  
          }
       }
```

which only return "My advice? Don't just get one copy", how can I get the whole text?

Update: Even if I remove all

"br"

tag from htmlnode, still when use the above code I only get "My advice? Don't just get one copy" part!!! any comment?

Comment: cant I use TakeWhile or something similar to get all texts??

Comment: Define a "text which doesnt have any html tag" ?

Comment: the text in my sample "if you know Ron Kaufman as i do..." belongs to only a div on top of the htmlpage, so in my htmlnode it doesnt have any tag literally

Comment: That's not a definition in HTML terms. All text nodes are children of a parent node.

Comment: yeah, its quite odd, but I need to do it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the code to this:

```
var allText = (reviewDiv.Descendants("div")
  .First(div => div.Attributes["style"].Value == "padding-top: 10px; clear: both; width: 100%;")
  .SelectNodes("./preceding-sibling::text()") ?? new HtmlNodeCollection(null)) 
  .Select(text => text.InnerText);
```

This should return an IEnumerable of strings with the text preceding the div with the intricate style.

Without having a little more of the surrounding HTML it's hard to tell whether this is exactly what you're after. I'm currently guessing that you have selected a div and that that div is the direct parent of this whole block of text (given your reference to a reviewDiv). Your HTML sample doesn't seem to contain this piece of HTML, so I'm making a few assumptions here.

With the following input:

> ```
> <div><div class="tiny" style="margin-bottom:0.5em;">
> <b><span class="h3color tiny">This review is from: </span>You Meet</b>
> </div>
> If you know Ron Kaufman as I do ...
> <br /><br />Whether you're the CEO....
> <br /><br />Written in a distinctive, ...
> <br /><br />My advice? Don't just get one copy
> <div style="padding-top: 10px; clear: both; width: 100%;"></div></div>
> ```

It extracts this:

> If you know Ron Kaufman as I do ...
>     Whether you're the CEO....
>     Written in a distinctive, ...
>     My advice? Don't just get one copy

To build a single string I used: `string extractedText = string.Join("", allText);`

Comment: does it also include "This review is from:" and "You Meet"?

Comment: it is not getting the text without <div> tag... which is important

Comment: did you test it? the output is exactly what I am looking for but when I tested your code I got "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Yes I tested it. It probably depends on what reviewDiv refers to, which is why I made the comment on the need to know a little bit about the surrounding HTML. Also, `SelectNodes` returns null and not an empty collection when no nodes are found, so adding `?? new HtmlNodeCollection()` after each call to `SelectNodes` might also resolve your issue.

Comment: still got the same error. updated with the more html code around, is it enough?

Comment: I've separated them and it works: HtmlNode afterReviewDiv = divReview.SelectSingleNode(@".//div[@style='padding-top: 10px; clear: both; width: 100%;']");
                                            var reviewNodes = afterReviewDiv.SelectNodes("./preceding-sibling::text()") ?? new HtmlNodeCollection(null);
                                            var txtReviewNodes = reviewNodes.Select(text => text.InnerText.Trim());